# Converting expression to another?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, .net-core, expression-trees

I have a little challenge which I don't know how to solve.

I need to convert from this `Expression<Func<TEntity, URequest, bool>>` to this `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

The 2nd is going to be used to query a data source.

The idea is this having a base class constructor with the following signature

```
abstract class Base
{
    Base(Expression<Func<TEntity, TRequest, bool>> expression) { .... }
}
```

I can provide an expression in the derived something like this

```
class Derived : Base 
{
   Derived() : 
        base ((enttiy, request) => entity.SomeProp == request.SomePropValue) { } 
}
```

This is used by the Base as such

```
/// Ctor
Base(Expression<Func<TEntity, TRequest, bool>> expression)
{
    _pipelineBuilder.AddFetchEntityStep (expression)
}
```

Where AddFetchEntityStep is a step in a pipeline

The pipeline looks like this.

Step 1 : FetchEntity
Step 2 : Executing
Step 3 : Validate
Step 3 : Executed

Now there are two ways of retrieving an entity by Id or by another property.

For this I have a

```
ReadOnlyRepository
{
    TEntity GetById<TEntity>(object id) { .... } 
    TEntity GetBy<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression) { .... }
```

In the AddFetchEntityStep I do a check in order to know what Get to invoke, something like

```
public void AddFetchEntityStep (Expression<Func<TEntity, URequest, bool>> expression = null)
{
     if (expression == null )
     {   
         _repo.GetById<TEntity>(1)
     }  

     else 
     {
         _repo.GetBy(.....) //// The problem 
     }
}
```

I know they are two different signatures
`Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>` and `Expression<Func<TEntity, TRequest, bool>>`

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Those are two different method signatures. If you want to use the second one, assign it to an expression that takes a `TEntity` argument and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply use lambda expression to convert an expression tree to another.

As long as the request parameter is not provided by the caller that specifies lambda expression , consider use `Func<URequest,Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>>` instead of `Expression<Func<TEntity, URequest, bool>>`.

And the lambda expression would look like this

`(request) => (enttiy) => entity.SomeProp == request.SomePropValue`.

Then your base class could call it to bind a 'request' object to the expression.

Btw, generic parameter names with prefix other than `T` is antipattern.

Comment: `Btw, generic parameter names with prefix other than T is antipattern.` Could you explain why or do you have a link explaining? I always see `T` as type param, but wouldn't it be clearer to name the parameter with the purpose?

Comment: @user2190035 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#names-of-generic-type-parameters