# Replace a parameter in an expression with a constant

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression

I have an expression of type `Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>>` and a constant of type `TElement`. I need an expression of type `Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>` with one of the parameters replaced by the constant. In other words, I need the body to the following method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> ReplaceParameter<TElement>
(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>> inputExpression,
    TElement element
)
{
    ...
}
```

If I call `ReplaceParameter((i1, i2) => i1 > i2, 5)`, I expect the result to be `i => i > 5`.

I was thinking, it might be able to recursively deconstruct and then reconstruct the input expression and replace all occurrences of the second parameter with a constant expression. Since there are so many different kind of expressions, I'm unsure on how to do that, though.

Comment: My answer to another question. Does it help for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153712/converting-expression-to-another/56160589#56160589

Comment: oh I forgot to mention, that I tried that approach as well (using `Func<TElement, Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>>`) and it works fine. It's fairly unintuitive to use however. I would prefer it to work with expressions of the form `(i1, i2) => i1 > i2` instead of `i1 => i2 => i1 > i2`.

Comment: It would be logically better to use higher-order function expression when binding an argument ahead of the execution. On the other hand, replacing the `Expression` tree is complex and uncertain, for it is quit hard to assume what expression structure the caller could provide, and to handle all cases that it could meet with.

Comment: @Alsein the framework provides a type *specifically so you don't have to worry about that complexity* - see the answers below

Comment: I don't think that you understand what I said properly. The complexity that I mentioned is that there is much possibility that the caller would pass arguments of expressions that you couldn't fully handle. There is certain to be a great amount of job to do but still much many bugs and defects on the ORM frameworks, that have no choice but to deal with the expressions. @MarcGravell

Comment: @Alsein that complexity isn't really altered in this scenario, though...

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, it seems not really so complex just to bind an argument, but still there are more easy and clear way to do. It would be better to use expression factory, wouldn't it

Comment: Btw, expression visiting may take time.

Comment: I think ExpressionVisitor is a pretty clean way to do this, thanks for the replies. Additionally, I found a different solution, which seems to be a bit more specific but also easier to understand and (potentially?) less performance intensive:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340778/4961688

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExpressionVisitor` is your friend:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> before = (x, y) => x * 2 == y + 1;
    var after = ReplaceParameter(before, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(after);
}
public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> ReplaceParameter<TElement>
(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>> inputExpression,
    TElement element
)
{
    var replacer = new Replacer(inputExpression.Parameters[0],
        Expression.Constant(element, typeof(TElement)));
    var body = replacer.Visit(inputExpression.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body,
        inputExpression.Parameters[1]);
}
class Replacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _from, _to;
    public Replacer(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        _from = from;
        _to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        => node == _from ? _to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Note that this does not automatically collapse pure constant expressions, i.e. the code shown results in:

```cs
y => ((3 * 2) == (y + 1))
```

You *could* however, if you wanted, try looking for `BinaryExpression` that only has `ConstantExpression` as inputs, and evaluate the node directly, again inside `Replacer`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor) which will helps you visit the expression and replace part of the expression.

```
public class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> ReplaceParameter<TElement>(
        Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>> inputExpression, 
        TElement element)
    {

        Expression body = inputExpression.Body;
        ReplaceParameterVisitor visitor = 
            new ReplaceParameterVisitor(inputExpression.Parameters[1], 
                                        Expression.Constant(element, typeof(TElement)));
        Expression newBody = visitor.Visit(body);

        Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> newExpression = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, Boolean>>(
                newBody, 
                new ParameterExpression[] { inputExpression.Parameters[0] });
        return newExpression;
    }

    private ReplaceParameterVisitor(
        ParameterExpression param, 
        ConstantExpression constant)
    {
        this._param = param;
        this._constant = constant;
    }

    private readonly ParameterExpression _param;
    private readonly ConstantExpression _constant;


    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == this._param)
        {
            return this._constant;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
Expression<Func<Int32, Int32, Boolean>> f = (i1, i2) => i1 > i2;
Expression<Func<Int32, Boolean>> f2 = ReplaceParameterVisitor.ReplaceParameter(f, 5);
Boolean b = f2.Compile()(4);
```

Comment: minor note: it is a good idea to use `Expression.Constant(element, typeof(TElement))`, just in case `element` is `null` (to avoid it complaining)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ExpressionVisitor` you could create a factory `Func` like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> ReplaceParameter<TElement>
(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>> inputExpression,
    TElement element
)
{
    var inner = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>
    (
        inputExpression.Body,
        inputExpression.Parameters[1]
    );
    var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>>>
    (
        inner,
        inputExpression.Parameters[0]
    );
    var factory = outer.Compile();
    return factory(element);
}
```

To make it even more useful, you could save `factory` and call it every time you want to replace a parameter:

```
public static Func<TElement, Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>> CreateFactory<TElement>
(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TElement, bool>> inputExpression
)
{
    var inner = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>
    (
        inputExpression.Body,
        inputExpression.Parameters[1]
    );
    var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>>>
    (
        inner,
        inputExpression.Parameters[0]
    );
    return outer.Compile();
}

public static void Test()
{
    var factory = CreateFactory<int>((i1, i2) => i1 > i2);
    var greater5 = factory(5);
    var greater2 = factory(2);
}
```

What is actually happening here?
When `inputExpression` is `(i1, i2) => i1 > i2` then `inner` would be `i1 => i1 > i2` and `outer`/`factory` would be `i2 => i1 => i1 > i2`.