# lambda expression function body to sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda, delegates

I would like to know if there is any way to do the next. I would like to extract compiled body of a function.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 5;
        Where2(p => new { V = p.Length == i });
        
    }

    public static void Where2<TResult>(Expression<Func<string, TResult>> func)
    {
        try
        {

            var body = (System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression)func.Body;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Output:");
            Console.WriteLine(body);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
        //dynamic operation = func.Body;   //

    }
}
```

> Output: new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(V = (p.Length ==
> value(TestDelegateFun.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).i))

So I would like to have the compiled body like :

> Output: new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(V = (p.Length ==
> 5))

Comment: It's possible, but it would require leveraging [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=net-6.0) to swap out the reference to the constant with the constant value itself.   For some inspiration, [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337454/replace-a-parameter-in-an-expression-with-a-constant) has some parallels to your question.

Comment: Note that you aren't referencing a constant - you are referencing a class field. How do you expect your method to know which fields should be replaced with their values?

Comment: Also, why are you creating an anonymous object in the lambda?

Comment: Thanks a lot @kirk woll !  ExpressionVisitor is working great!

Comment: @NetMage I,m using it for my SQL query to make my code readable.

Comment: @MehdiSh. great, glad you made some headway!

Comment: @NetMage while it's a "class field" it's also effectively a constant since the field is merely the compiler generated lifting of the constant declared in code.

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't see that, `i` is a real variable (class field). Depending on how the `Expression` tree is used, `i`'s value could be changed before the tree is executed or processed.

Comment: @NetMage I think you taking "constant" more literally than I intended.  To be more clear, I was pointing out that the value of `i` has a compile-time provided value of `5` that can be obtained through the expression tree.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FilterConstructor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<ExpressionType, string> _logicalOperators;
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>> _typeConverters;
        static FilterConstructor()
        {
            //mappings for table, shown above
            _logicalOperators = new Dictionary<ExpressionType, string>
            {
                [ExpressionType.Not] = "not",
                [ExpressionType.GreaterThan] = "gt",
                [ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual] = "ge",
                [ExpressionType.LessThan] = "lt",
                [ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual] = "le",
                [ExpressionType.Equal] = "==",
                [ExpressionType.Not] = "not",
                [ExpressionType.AndAlso] = "and",
                [ExpressionType.OrElse] = "or"
            };

            //if type is string we will wrap it into single quotes
            //if it is a DateTime we will format it like datetime'2008-07-10T00:00:00Z'
            //bool.ToString() returns "True" or "False" with first capital letter, so .ToLower() is applied
            //if it is one of the rest "simple" types we will just call .ToString() method on it
            _typeConverters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>
            {
                [typeof(string)] = x => $"'{x}'",
                [typeof(DateTime)] =
                  x => $"'{((DateTime)x).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")}'",
                [typeof(bool)] = x => x.ToString().ToLower()
            };
        }

        private StringBuilder _queryStringBuilder;
        private Stack<string> _fieldNames;
        public FilterConstructor()
        {
            //here we will collect our query
            _queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //will be discussed below
            _fieldNames = new Stack<string>();
        }

        //entry point
        public string GetQuery(LambdaExpression predicate)
        {
            
            Visit(predicate.Body);
            var query = _queryStringBuilder.ToString();
            _queryStringBuilder.Clear();

            return query;
        }

        //protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        //{
        //    //assume we only allow not (!) unary operator:
        //    if (node.NodeType != ExpressionType.Not)
        //        throw new NotSupportedException("Only not(\"!\") unary operator is supported!");

        //    _queryStringBuilder.Append($"{_logicalOperators[node.NodeType]} ");//!

        //    _queryStringBuilder.Append("(");                                   //(!
        //                                                                       //go down from a tree
        //    Visit(node.Operand);                                               //(!expression
        //    _queryStringBuilder.Append(")");                                   //(!expression)

        //    //we should return expression, it will allow to create new expression based on existing one,
        //    //but, at our case, it is not needed, so just return initial node argument
        //    return node;
        //}

        //corresponds to: and, or, greater than, less than, etc.
        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            _queryStringBuilder.Append("(");                                    //(
                                                                                //left side of binary operator
            Visit(node.Left);                                                   //(leftExpr

            _queryStringBuilder.Append($" {_logicalOperators[node.NodeType]} ");//(leftExpr and

            //right side of binary operator
            Visit(node.Right);                                                  //(leftExpr and RighExpr
            _queryStringBuilder.Append(")");                                    //(leftExpr and RighExpr)

            return node;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            

            if (node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant
               ||
               node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                _fieldNames.Push(node.Member.Name);
                Visit(node.Expression);
            }
            else
                //corresponds to: x.Customer - just write "Customer"
                _queryStringBuilder.Append(node.Member.Name);
            return node;
        }

        //corresponds to: 1, "Tom", instance of NameSpace+<>c__DisplayClass12_0, instance of Order, i.e.
        //any expression with value
        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            //just write value
            _queryStringBuilder.Append(GetValue(node.Value));
            return node;
        }

        private string GetValue(object input)
        {
            var type = input.GetType();
            //if it is not simple value
            if (type.IsClass && type != typeof(string))
            {
                //proper order of selected names provided by means of Stack structure
                var fieldName = _fieldNames.Pop();
                var fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldName);
                object value;
                if (fieldInfo != null)
                    //get instance of order    
                    value = fieldInfo.GetValue(input);
                else
                    //get value of "Customer" property on order
                    value = type.GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(input);
                return GetValue(value);
            }
            else
            {
                //our predefined _typeConverters
                if (_typeConverters.ContainsKey(type))
                    return _typeConverters[type](input);
                else
                    //rest types
                    return input.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's totally unclear how this answers your question. It's just an unexplained slab of code that apparently does what you want, but it has no educational value, which is Stack Overflow's prime mission.